# How to get unique values from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have address array. I want to get unique address records from below array. I have used lots of logic but all fails to extract unique address. If we get any differences between keys like address_one, address_two etc. with another one, then I will consider as unique, but here some array values same with others.

```
Array
(    
0 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => 'qqqqqqqqqq',
            'address_two' => 'wwwwww',
            'zipcode' => '212121',
            'country_id' => '1',
            'country_name' => 'United States',
            'state_id' => '5',
            'state_name' => 'AP',
            'city_id' => '3',
            'city_name' => 'Bhopal'
        ),    
1 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => 'lkl',
            'address_two' => 'ik2',
            'zipcode' => '564564',
            'country_id' => '1',
            'country_name' => 'United States',
            'state_id' => '1',
            'state_name' => 'Madhya Pradesh',
            'city_id' => '1',
            'city_name' => 'Indore'
        ),    
2 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => 'ace1',
            'address_two' => 'caldrys1',
            'zipcode' => '564561',
            'country_id' => '91',
            'country_name' => 'Guinea',
            'state_id' => '3',
            'state_name' => 'AL',
            'city_id' => '3',
            'city_name' => 'Bhopal'
        ),    
3 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => '',
            'address_two' => '',
            'zipcode' => '',
            'country_id' => '',
            'country_name' => '',
            'state_id' => '',
            'state_name' => '',
            'city_id' => '',
            'city_name' => ''
        ),    
4 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => '',
            'address_two' => '',
            'zipcode' => '',
            'country_id' => '',
            'country_name' => '',
            'state_id' => '',
            'state_name' => '',
            'city_id' => '',
            'city_name' => ''
        ),    
5 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => 'lkl',
            'address_two' => 'ik2',
            'zipcode' => '564564',
            'country_id' => '1',
            'country_name' => 'United States',
            'state_id' => '1',
            'state_name' => 'Madhya Pradesh',
            'city_id' => '1',
            'city_name' => 'Indore'
        ),    
6 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => 'Ace',
            'address_two' => 'Matru Line',
            'zipcode' => '483504',
            'country_id' => '100',
            'country_name' => 'India',
            'state_id' => '1',
            'state_name' => 'Madhya Pradesh',
            'city_id' => '2',
            'city_name' => 'Katni'
        ),    
7 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => 'lkl',
            'address_two' => 'ik2',
            'zipcode' => '564564',
            'country_id' => '1',
            'country_name' => 'United States',
            'state_id' => '1',
            'state_name' => 'Madhya Pradesh',
            'city_id' => '1',
            'city_name' => 'Indore'
        ),
8 => Array
        (
            'address_one' => 'ace1',
            'address_two' => 'caldrys1',
            'zipcode' => '564561',
            'country_id' => '91',
            'country_name' => 'Guinea',
            'state_id' => '3',
            'state_name' => 'AL',
            'city_id' => '3',
            'city_name' => 'Bhopal'
        )

);
```

Comment: 1) Have you tried something? Show your attempts! 2) What is the current output and what do you expect to get?

Comment: @Rizier123: 4 upvotes for this question and 4 upvotes for the answer. What on _earth_ is going on? `;=D`

Comment: @halfer earth is broken with many fatal syntax errors in it :} Like this question.

Comment: I have used lots of complex method, using loop and keeping values another array but all of things not working properly.  Also used In_array, array_intersect, array_diff etc.

Comment: Would you give us an example of all of the things that did not work properly, edited into your question? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this to get unique array.

```
$output_array = array_unique($input_array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 5):

To get unique multidimensional array you can use this :

```
$output_array = array_map(
    "unserialize",
    array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input_array))
);
```

Comment: Given how difficult the original post was to understand, I am impressed you got it in 17 minutes without any clarifications required. You've managed to get additional congratulatory messages as well, and four quick upvotes - good work! However, please be aware that if any of you know each other, there is no value in answering each other's questions - voting ring detection is very good on Stack Overflow, and is soon reversed.